# Define an url for a react component

Tags: reactjs, url, hyperlink

I have developed a small window for a chatbot with React.This window opens when the user clicks a button.
Now I want a way to integrate this button into any site or application I want. For example, I want to associate a URL with this button so that if this bonton is on the site A, in the site B it is enough for me to provide the URL of this button to load it in the site B. Thus the users of the site B will have access to the bot. And this should work that site B is in HTML, JavaScript, etc.

How to do this ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: maybe iframes? https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component

Comment: I think this does not solve my problem since even if I wrap it in a "Frame" component, I do not have a URL that allows me to access this Frame. Let's take a simple HTML example. Suppose we have a page that displays the list of customers "https://myapp/home/listCustomers" on site A, now on site B just have a link like <a src = "https://myapp/home/listCustomers "> List of customers </a> if we want to access the list of customers of the site A.I want to do exactly the same with React components. Thank you in advance